# Python classs en function seperated?

Tags: python

Why my IDE separates the class and functions from each other and if I change and run, I get an error like this: `TypeError: check_turn() missing 1 required positional argument: 'turn'`

**This is how my code first looks like**

```
class Dev:
    players = ['Bob', 'Anne']
    turn = [0, 1]

    def check_turn(self, players, turn):
        for i in turn:
            if i == 0:
                print("It's {} turn".format(players[0]))
            elif i == 1:
                print("It's {} turn".format(players[1]))
            return i

    check_turn(players, turn)
```

**This is after I need to change it**

```
def check_turn(players, turn):
    for i in turn:
        if i == 0:
            print("It's {} turn".format(players[0]))
        elif i == 1:
            print("It's {} turn".format(players[1]))
        return i


class Dev:
    players = ['Bob', 'Anne']
    turn = [0, 1]

    check_turn(players, turn)
```

Comment: Your after is fine; did you leave the `self` argument when you moved `check_turn` out of the class? Why are you calling `check_turn` in the `class` statement in the first place?

Comment: I agree with @chepner, what is going on here? I don’t think that use of classes makes much sense, it feels like ham-fisted OOP.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I believe there is no meaning of using a class, using a simple method will be done.

> Classes provide a means of bundling data and functionality together.
>   Creating a new class creates a new type of object, allowing new
>   instances of that type to be made. Each class instance can have
>   attributes attached to it for maintaining its state. Class instances
>   can also have methods (defined by its class) for modifying its state.

```
players = ['Bob', 'Anne']
turn = [0, 1]

def check_turn(players, turn):
    for i in turn:
        if i == 0:
          print("It's {} turn".format(players[0]))
        elif i == 1:
          print("It's {} turn".format(players[1]))
        return i

check_turn(players, turn)
```

The output :

```
It's Bob turn
```

But if you want to run  check_turn() method when creating an instance of the class,you have to correct it by :

```
class Dev:
    players = ['Bob', 'Anne']
    turn = [0, 1]
    def check_turn(self, players, turn):
      for i in turn:
          if i == 0:
            print("It's {} turn".format(players[0]))
          elif i == 1:
            print("It's {} turn".format(players[1]))
          return i
    def __init__(self):
        self.check_turn(self.players, self.turn)

Dev()
```

The output :

```
It's Bob turn
```

Comment: Why do you need to call the class outside the class? and I still get the recommendation to `make function from method`

Comment: Ah, oke. I guess I'm just confused because in C# and Java there is always a class automatically made for you. If I would make this code in there and call it, there would be no problem. Sometimes I also see something confusing like more classes in 1 file, which I never have seen in C# for example.